# CSS only text Submenu (under a sprite menu) is misaligned in chrome/safari only

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit, submenu

I have a working sprite menu, and want to add a vertical submenu under one of the items.  I have it working perfectly in ie and firefox, however in webkit browsers (chrome and safari), the submenu renders to the left of the right margin of the containing li, making the menu unusable.  I have tried every css tip I could find to make this work, including overriding the webkit -40padding, yet everything I have tried makes no difference to the alignment in those browsers.

[test page](http://www.comedyinhighdefinition.com/droptest.php)

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer below solved the problem in webkit, but caused another in IE.  The answer was actually to put back the position:relative, and to change the display: inline to display: block in the top level menu #navigation (ul id).  Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find your `#navigation > li { position:relative }` and remove `position:relative`

Comment: Not sure if this is a separate question, but the sub-menu only appears right of the main container in ie7, any ideas?

Comment: hmm... i don't have ie7... as far as i can remember it's a bug that has something to do with absolute positioning. Google: ie7 absolute position bug... Sorry. can't help any further with ie :)